# Lines don't overlap when they should Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, line, graphic

I'm drawing lines in a JFrame on a self made gridPanel.

Problem is, I draw the lines between 2 points. When I have a line that is between point 1 and point 2 and a line between point 2 and point 3, the lines should connect. This however isn,t the case, there is a small gap in between, no idea why. But it isn't drawing till the end of the specified point. (start point is correct.)

Here is the code of the JFrame:

```
public void initialize(){
     this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
    gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    gridPane.setSize(this.getPreferredSize());
    gridPane.setLocation(0, 0);
    this.add(gridPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //createSampleLabyrinth();
    drawWall(0,5,40,5);  //These are the 2 lines that don't connect.
    drawWall(40,5,80,5);
    this.pack();
}
```

drawWall calls a method that calls a method in GridPane.
The relevant code in gridPane:

```
/**
 * Draws a wall on this pane. With the starting point being x1, y1 and its end x2,y2.
 * @param x1
 * @param y1
 * @param x2
 * @param y2
 */
public void drawWall(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    Wall wall = new Wall(x1,y1,x2,y2, true);
    wall.drawGraphic();
    wall.setLocation(x1, y1);
    wall.setSize(10000,10000);
    this.add(wall, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    this.repaint();
}
```

This method creates a wall and puts it in the Jframe.
The relevant code of the wall:

```
public class Wall extends JPanel {
private int x1;
private int x2;
private int y1;
private int y2;
private boolean black;

/**
 * x1,y1 is the start point of the wall (line) end is x2,y2
 * 
 * @param x1
 * @param y1
 * @param x2
 * @param y2
 */
public Wall(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, boolean black) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.black = black;
    setOpaque(false);
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void drawGraphic() {
    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    if(black){
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(8));
    } else {
        g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
    }
    g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

}

So, where am I going wrong? The true/false is to determine if the wall should be black or yellow, nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the main layout as `BorderLayout` using `this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());`

You then add the `GridPane` to the center position `this.add(gridPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);`

You then try and add the walls to the main layout using `this.add(wall, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);` ... But the main layout is a `BorderLayout`

This is going to cause you some issues

**UPDATED**

The other problem you have is in the `Wall#paintComponent` method.

You are drawing the lines offset from the `x1` and `y1` positions, but the component has already being positioned at this point.

The top, left corner of any component is always 0x0

The line `g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);` should read more like...

```
int x = x2 - x1;
int y = y2 - y1;
g2.drawLine(0, 0, x, y);
```

**UPDATED**

You should also avoid setting the size of your components to some arbitary value (such 1000x1000) and rely more on the ability for your components to give you feedback...

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    int width = Math.max(x1, x2) - Math.min(x1, x2);
    int height = Math.max(y1, y2) - Math.min(y1, y2);

    if (black) {
        width += 8;
        height += 8;
    } else {
        width += 3;
        height += 3;
    }

    return new Dimension(width, height);
}
```

Then when adding the `Wall`, you can use `wall.setSize(wall.getPreferredSize())` instead...

Comment: Can't remember exactly why I did it that way. How would you recommend I solve it?

Comment: From the looks of the code, the expectation is the walls will be placed on a `JLayeredPane`.  I would work out a way to get them onto one, either by making the `GridPane` extend from `JLayeredPane` or adding one to the `GridPane` (making the `GridPane`'s layout a `BorderLayout`) then adding the walls to it.  The other solution would be to investigate the shape API

Comment: Ah, I confused the positioning with the length! A thousand thanks.